# ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file XAMPP

Tags: mysql, macos, xampp

I know there are a lot of similar problems, but I have to post this because I am not finding a solution yet. Below is what happens when I try to run mysql. Not using homebrew here! I originally fixed the problem by killing the process ID for mysqld, but since I shut my computer down and relocated, then restarted, I am getting this error again. It seems to be the same except the difference with this error is the *local.pid* part. This was not in my original error message and wandering how to fix this?

Original error fixed by killing the process ID:

ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/genevieve-ouellons-macbook-pro.pid)

The new error after shutdown, relocate and trying to start:

genevieve-ouellons-macbook-pro:bin genevieveouellon$ cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin
genevieve-ouellons-macbook-pro:bin genevieveouellon$ ./mysql.server start
Warning: World-writable config file '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf' is ignored

Starting MySQL

. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/genevieve-ouellons-macbook-pro.local.pid).

Anyone have this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It worked by using these two commands:

cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin

sudo ./mysql.server start

Using sudo is the keyword that made the difference this time around.

Comment: It doesn't really help! :/

Comment: Didn't work for me: `Starting MySQL ................................................................................​..................... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/gmac.local.pid).`

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start
```

Above command worked in my case, only if the port is empty..

If this results error, restart server/mac and try the above command.. Hope this helps for someone..

Comment: Didn't work for me: `Starting MySQL ................................................................................​..................... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/gmac.local.pid).`

Answer (score 0):

Might've been deleted when you manually restarted mysql or renamed your machine. Not sure about XAMPP but when using mysql on OSX this is my go-to..

1. cd into `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/`
2. `rm -rf *.local.err` (deletes file)
3. `touch YOURUSERNAME.local.pid` (generates *.local.pid file the error thrown was complaining about)
4. cd back into your project and restart mysql using `mysql.server start`

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved this issue... (3 days later)

1. Open up YOURUSERNAME.local.err in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/ with a text editor.
2. I had "InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files"
3. Then follow instructions on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html as it states in the log file
4. Add `innodb_force_recovery = 2` after line: `[mysqld]` to your my.cnf located in `/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/`
5. Then `sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start`
6. Give it a minute and it should repair itself
7. Comment out with `#innodb_foce_recovery = 2` in my.cnf

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately none of possible solutions did not helped me.
Still the Mysql was not able to start and in terminal I saw only /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/: "ERROR!" without any further info

I simply reinstalled XAMPP again - worked